# Select all dates between without array

Tags: php, sql, laravel

is there any way to display all the dates including weekend and all the dates to start and end
Here is the code

```
if(request()->ajax())
 {
  if(!empty($request->from_date))
  {


    $data  = DB::table('Checkinout')

            ->join('Z_MemRecord','Checkinout.Userid','=','Z_MemRecord.uid')
            ->select(DB::raw("FORMAT(MIN (Checkinout.CheckTime), 'hh:mm tt') AS Ontime, FORMAT (max(Checkinout.CheckTime), 'hh:mm tt') AS OffTime, Checkinout.Userid,Z_MemRecord.Uname,FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'MMM dd yyyy') as dates,FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'dddd') as hour"))

              ->where('Checkinout.CheckTime', '>', $request->from_date)->where('Checkinout.CheckTime', '<=', $request->to_date)
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("Convert(Date, Checkinout.CheckTime),Checkinout.Userid,Z_MemRecord.Uname,FORMAT(Checkinout.CheckTime, 'MMM dd yyyy'),FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'dddd')"))
            ->orderbyRaw('Convert(Date, Checkinout.CheckTime) desc')

            ->get();        
  }
```

Jan 10, 2019 is not displayed.
[image]

Comment: i think date format is an issue here

Comment: please. how do i fix it?

Comment: what is your date format in database ?

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss that's the format in my database

Comment: did that work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the answer

```
->whereDate('Checkinout.CheckTime', '>=', $request->from_date)->whereDate('Checkinout.CheckTime', '<=',$request->to_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated query. you need to do something like this

```php
if(request()->ajax())
 {
  if(!empty($request->from_date))
  {


    $data  = DB::table('Checkinout')

            ->join('Z_MemRecord','Checkinout.Userid','=','Z_MemRecord.uid')
            ->select(DB::raw("FORMAT(MIN (Checkinout.CheckTime), 'hh:mm tt') AS Ontime, FORMAT (max(Checkinout.CheckTime), 'hh:mm tt') AS OffTime, Checkinout.Userid,Z_MemRecord.Uname,FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'MMM dd yyyy') as dates,FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'dddd') as hour"))

              ->where(`date('yyyy-mm-dd','Checkinout.CheckTime')`, '>', $request->from_date)->where(`date('yyyy-mm-dd','Checkinout.CheckTime')`, '<=', $request->to_date)
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("Convert(Date, Checkinout.CheckTime),Checkinout.Userid,Z_MemRecord.Uname,FORMAT(Checkinout.CheckTime, 'MMM dd yyyy'),FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'dddd')"))
            ->orderbyRaw('Convert(Date, Checkinout.CheckTime) desc')

            ->get();        
      }
    }
```

Comment: Still not working, and idk why laravel stops working after i run it.

Comment: yeeee, i think. i tried to run it from FORMAT('table',' 'MMM dd yyyy') still not. lol

Comment: you still there?